# Derivation of Yang-Mills functional

Tags: differential-geometry, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

I was trying to calculate the critical points of Yang-Mills functional. And I failed to show that $F_{A+ta}=F_{A}+t\nabla_Aa+t^2a\wedge a$. Here is my attempt:
Suppose all calculation is in a local chart. Then,
$$F_{A+ta}=d(A+ta)+(A+ta)\wedge(A+ta)=dA+A\wedge A+t(A\wedge a+a\wedge A)+t^2a\wedge a=F_A+t(da+A\wedge a+a\wedge A)+t^2a\wedge a.$$
However, I believe that it should hold $\nabla_Aa=(d+[A,-])a=da+A\wedge a-a\wedge A$, which takes the wrong sign.

Where is my fault? Could anyone help me please?

Comment: Recall that when $\omega$ is a matrix-valued $k$-form and $\eta$ is a matrix-valued $\ell$-form, then $[\omega,\eta] = \omega\wedge\eta + (-1)^{k\ell+1}\eta\wedge\omega$. So $[A,a] = A\wedge a + a\wedge A$ and $[A,F] = A\wedge F-F\wedge A$.